# RegEx for ignoring defined boundaries

Tags: regex, string, replace

**Problem**

I'm trying to retrieve information from a text file but I'm struggling for to retrieve the content of the field "Rationale":
Indeed, my problem is that I want to ignore the pattern : **List Paragraph\txx)** with x a digit. 
However, there's some lines that are starting with **List Paragraph\t(x)**. 
In short, if the character right after List Paragraph\t is not a "(", I want to ignore the digits **xx)** but if it is followed by a "(", starting to catch now. (see Expected results section below)

**Text**

```
List Paragraph  36) Rationale-1 - Details on the context:
List Paragraph  37) None.
Normal  
List Paragraph  38) 2 - Statement complements:
List Paragraph  39) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (1) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (2) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (3) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (4) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (5) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (6) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (7) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  40) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  41) 3 - Statement justification:
List Paragraph  42) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  43) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  44) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  45) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  46) Attached Files: Rationale-
Normal
```

First, I'm catching everything starting right after "Rationale-" until the last character before "List Paragraph\t46) Attached Files: Rationale-" with this regex:

```
^List\sParagraph\t\d+\)\sRationale-([\s\S]+?)(?=^List\sParagraph\t\d+\)\sAttached\sFiles:\sRationale-)
```

With this, I have the following:

```
1 - Details on the context:
List Paragraph  37) None.
Normal  
List Paragraph  38) 2 - Statement complements:
List Paragraph  39) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (1) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (2) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (3) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (4) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (5) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (6) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  (7) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  40) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  41) 3 - Statement justification:
List Paragraph  42) Blablablabla
Normal  
List Paragraph  43) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  44) Blablablabla
List Paragraph  45) Blablablabla
```

Now, I don't know, from this point, how to get the expected result...

**Expected results**

```
1 - Details on the context:
None.

2 - Statement complements:
Blablablabla
(1)Blablablabla
(2)Blablablabla
(3)Blablablabla
(4)Blablablabla
(5)Blablablabla
(6)Blablablabla
(7)Blablablabla 

Blablablabla

3 - Statement justification:
Blablablabla

Blablablabla
Blablablabla
Blablablabla
```

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to select all that you want and replace with an empty string:

```
^(?:.*?\bRationale-|Normal|List Paragraph\t(?:\d+\)[ \t]*)?)[ \t]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M2eTBm/1)

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `.*?\bRationale-` Match 0+ times any char except a newline non greedy and match wordboundary and `Rationale-`
  - `|` Or
  - `Normal$` Match Normal and assert end of the string
  - `|` Or
  - `List Paragraph\t` Match `List Paragraph` and tab
  - `(?:\d+\)[ \t]*)?` Optional part to match 1+ digits, `)` followed by 0+ times a space or tab
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `[ \t]*` Match 0+ times a space or tab

If you want to get a match instead you could capture all that comes after in a capturing group by adding `(.*)` to the end of the pattern.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgOkbm/1)

If the engine supports `\K` to forget what was currently matched you could add `\K.*` after it instead.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pgOkbm/2)